# What is this division-like operation on polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, notation, linear-transformations

I'm looking for **the name** of a "division-like" operation $f$ such that $f(P,x^n)$ walks over the $x$-rooted terms of the polynomial $P$ and performs integer division on each exponent, dividing by $n$, discarding remainders, so e.g. $f(x^{256},x^2)=x^{128}$ and $f(x^{11},x^2)=x^5$. And for example given $P=x+2x^2+3x^3+2x^4+x^5$, then $f(P,x^2)=1+5x+3x^2$, and $f(P,x^3)=3+6x$.

There should be an identity $f(Q,x)=Q$ for any polynomial $Q$ involving the variable $x$.

The operation should also distribute over addition, so $f(P,x+x^n+x^m)$ should equal $P+f(P,x^n)+f(P,x^m)$.

Does this operation have a name?

Comment: This is not clear.  $n$ is a polynomial?  Odd notation.  What does it mean to say that $f(P(x),x)$ is the identity?  Do you mean that it equals the polynomial $x$?

Comment: Sorry, the edit doesn't clarify anything.  How do you know that $f(x+2x^2+3x^3+2x^4+x^5,x^2)=1+5x+3x^2$?  What rule ought we to apply to confirm or reject that result?  Also, I'm guessing that the first term in your supposed computation of $f(P,x+x^n+x^m)$ is supposed to be $P(x)$ not $x$, but it's really just a guess.

Comment: @lulu: you are right, $f(P,x)=P$.

Comment: The algorithm is in the question. "f(P,xn) walks over the x-rooted terms of the polynomial P and performs integer division on each exponent, dividing by n, discarding remainders". What's unclear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a linear map on the vector space of polynomials.

i.e.

$f(P,x^2) = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\&&1&1&\\&&&&1&1\\\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\\3\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\5\\3\end{bmatrix}$

No, this doesn't have a name as far as I am aware:

$f(P,x^3) = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&\\&&&1&1&1\\\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\\3\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3\\6\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Now accepted, meaning it is the desired thing.... Some amazing mind-reading went into this answer.

Comment: Can you make explicit the criteria for setting a particular cell of the left hand matrix to 1?